# Using Struts2 in NetBeans6.9

Tags: struts2, struts

Im newly using Struts2 now,but previously i used to work with Struts1.3.While using struts2 with netbeans6.9 IDE i'm facing problem.Actually i want to know what's the real difference between struts1&2 on implementation?.Is there any difference between them in the development?

Comment: Look at the **[Struts2 Guides](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.8.1/docs/guides.html)**, topic : **Struts 1 to Struts 2** (_Comparing Struts 1 and 2_, _Struts 1 Solutions_, _Migrating Applications to Struts 2_, _etc_)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this thread will help: [Struts 1.x vs Struts 2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867970/struts-1-x-vs-struts-2-x)